# Possible bug in ListDensityPlot in Mathematica12

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 12.0.0**

---

I'm having some problems with `ListDensityPlot` in Mathematica 12 on MacOS Mojave.

Here is the code:

```
test = Import["https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ypdo4pdh9q86j5/test.csv?dl=1"];
ListDensityPlot[test, PlotRange -> All, InterpolationOrder -> 0]
```

(data can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ypdo4pdh9q86j5/test.csv?dl=0)

Output in MMA11.3

> [image]

Output in MMA 12

> [image]

In v12 there are a lot of unwanted triangles in the plot. Any idea of what the problem might be?

EDIT: 
I forgot to mention that the problem "disappears" with any value different than 0 assigned to InterpolationOrder.

EDIT 2: 
It actually seems to be a genuine bug, so I added the bugs tag and reported to mathematica support.

Comment: Can confirm on 64bit Windows 10  (Version 1809) box.

Comment: `InterpolationOrder -> 1` seems to give the same (correct?) output for 10.4, 11.3, and 12 (Windows 10).

Comment: @JimB yes, any interpolation value != 0 seems to work fine as I mentioned in the edit.

Comment: Sorry.  I went to have breakfast and didn't notice the update.  I'll delete my comment shortly.  Overlaying the (x,y) points shows the triangles occurring where the points are.  Don't know if that adds anything or not.

Comment: No worries and no need to delete it. It's "good" too know that there is consistency between the different os. I was afraid it was yet another bug on macos only!

Comment: This is still an issue as of Feb 15, 2020. Windows 10 64-bit, MMA 12.0. This is really frustrating as I use ListDensityPlot for my research and interpolation is generally not a good thing for what I do.

Comment: @Kai pls report to Wolfram so that they might address the problem sooner

Comment: This issue appears to have been resolved in MMA 12.1

Comment: For me, I see it as of 12.3 with order>1, but I just overlay with no interpolation

Answer (score 1):

A workaround that did the job sufficiently well for me was to overlay the plots with InterpolationOrder -> 1 and InterpolationOrder -> 0 using Show[]:

```
Show[ListDensityPlot[test, PlotRange -> All, InterpolationOrder -> 1],ListDensityPlot[test, PlotRange -> All, InterpolationOrder -> 0]]
```